# yii framework select the values in dropdownlist

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I am new to frame work. I need to populate the value in dropdownlist.

I used the following code to display the values in dropdown

`echo $form->dropDownList($model,'pagetype', $Page_Type); ?>`

It displays the options in the dropdown.

I want to populate the selected value in the dropdown list.

The saved values are in $savedValues array.

I dont know how to apply the selected option in the dropdownlist.

Comment: Why do you have a `$savedValues` array? Do you need to select a value from the dropdown or you want to add other options besides the ones defined in `$Page_Type`? If you need to mark the selected option, @DCoder answer is absolutely right.

Comment: I saved some values in Database. The database result is stored in $savedValues  array. From this array i want to show the selected value in dropdown. i.e In the drop down i have three options ('one', 'two', 'three'). I choosed option 'two'. So it is saved in database. So while editing the form i need to populate the option 'two' as selected.

Comment: You should set `$model->pagetype` to the selected value (stored in the database), and it will be automatically selected from the list

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [documentation for CActiveForm::dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#dropDownList-detail) ? It determines the selected option automatically, in this case it'll be the one matching `$model->pagetype`.

Comment: Yes. I already used the following $model->pagetype=$savedvalues['PageType'];  But it is not selected the saved option

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump($Page_Type, $model->pagetype);` and add that to your post? It would be helpful to see what html options you're generating.

Comment: It results some array. Is there any option to populate the selected value in dropdown