# populate the value inside the FCK editor YII extension

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I want to populate the value in the editor. 
Normally we used `$oFCKeditor->Value` to display the content.

For Yii fck extention what is the parameter?

```
 $this->widget('application.extensions.fckeditor.FCKEditorWidget',array(
"model"=>$model,                # Data-Model
"attribute"=>'content',         # Attribute in the Data-Model
"height"=>'400px',
"width"=>'100%',

"fckeditor"=>Yii::app()->basePath."/../fckeditor/fckeditor.php",
                                # Path to fckeditor.php
"fckBasePath"=>Yii::app()->baseUrl."/fckeditor/",
                                # Relative Path to the Editor (from Web-Root)
"config" => array("EditorAreaCSS"=>Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/css/index.css',),
```

What is the parameter to display the value in the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value set in FCKeditor is retrieved from `model`:

```
"model"=>$model,                # Data-Model
"attribute"=>'content',         # Attribute in the Data-Model
```

This sets the FCKEditor value to `$model->content`.

If you need to set a predefined value, you could simply do this before displaying the widget:

```
$model->content = 'Some text goes here';
```

Comment: One more help. Please see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256729/yii-framework-select-the-values-in-dropdownlist    Do you have any idea about this?